# Adding a check combobox to an CMFCToolbar

Tags: cmfctoolbar

Looking for a solution to adding a check combobox to a CMFCToolbar. I took a quick look at the MFC Feature Pack but nothing pop out at me.

MFC, c++

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use CMFCToolBarMenuButton if I can get it to work.

T